# Keyword not supported: 'metadata' + MySQL

Tags: c#, mysql, web-config, entity-framework-5, connection-string

### The error

[image: The error]

### When it happens

I'm attempting to create a simple controller using a ViewModel as model.

### Connection String

```
<connectionStrings>
   <add name="BoaPropostaEntities"
        connectionString="metadata=res://*/Models.MyApp.csdl|res://*/Models.MyApp.ssdl|res://*/Models.MyApp.msl;provider=MySql.Data.MySqlClient;provider connection string='server=localhost;user id=root;password=root;persistsecurityinfo=True;database=mydatabase'"
        providerName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient"/>
```

### Web.Config spotlight

I also added to **Web.Config** some settings:

```
<system.data>
  <DbProviderFactories>
  <clear />
  <add name="MySQL Data Provider" 
       invariant="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" 
       description=".Net Framework Data Provider for MySQL"
       type="MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlClientFactory, MySql.Data, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d"/>
</DbProviderFactories>
```

And:

```
<entityFramework>
  <defaultConnectionFactory type="MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlClientFactory, MySql.Data"/>
  <contexts>
    <context type="MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlProviderServices, MySql.Data.Entity"/>
  </contexts>
</entityFramework>
```

All references seems to be okay.

### The question

Ideas to resolve my problem?

### Environment

Windows 8.1 + Visual Studio 2013 + MVC 4 + MySQL 5.6 + Connector/Net 6.8.3 + MySQL for Visual Studio Plug-In 1.1.0 + Entity Framework 5

### What I already tried

- I already tried to go with EF 6 — no scaffolding support then I give it up;
- I already tried to use a lower version of Connector/Net (such as 6.6.x ~ 6.7.x), but I get another problems;

### Duplicated?

I already searched in lots of topics about this subject. Unfortunatelly, until now, without success. I'm thinking that my problem is related specifically with my connectionString.

*If you want, post the topics related — I can confirm that isn't my solution. Anyway, sorry about one more topic about this, but nothing else is helping me.*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's an EF connection string, not a MySQL connection string.

You need  `providerName="System.Data.EntityClient"`.

Comment: What's the InnerException?

Comment: My ViewModel was the problem and I don't know why. I just changed the model and everything goes okay. By the way, thanks for your help, SLaks. Happy new year and hope you the best!